# Widget image cant be updated on Samsung s4 android 4.4 device

Tags: android, image, widget

Widget images are not updated only on android 4.4 Samsung s4 device however it works on other android 4.1 and etc. Updating the image is the only problem. There is no problem in updating text.
The problem is maybe in setimageviewUri.
If you have any idea please share.
Thanks for helping

```
widget's class :


enter code here
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
resources= context.getResources();
sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES,    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
partnerOneImage=sharedpreferences.getString(partnerOneImageKey,"");
partnerTwoImage=sharedpreferences.getString(partnerTwoImageKey,"");
startDateDay = sharedpreferences.getInt(startDateDayKey, -1);
startDateMonth = sharedpreferences.getInt(startDateMonthKey, -1);
startDateYear = sharedpreferences.getInt(startDateYearKey, -1);
getBackgroundImage = sharedpreferences.getString(backgroundImageKey,"");
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetmain3x3);
Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, AddDate.class);
    configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds);  // Identifies the particular widget...
configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.widget31, Uri.parse(""));
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.widget31, Uri.parse(partnerOneImage));
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.widget33, Uri.parse(""));
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.widget33, Uri.parse(partnerTwoImage));
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView3x3, getPassedDays() + " " + resources.getString(R.string.days));
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.backgroundImage2, Uri.parse(""));
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.backgroundImage2, Uri.parse(getBackgroundImage));

 PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, configIntent, 0);
 remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget3x3all, configPendingIntent);
 remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget31,configPendingIntent);
 remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget32,configPendingIntent);
 remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget33,configPendingIntent);
 appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);


}

and its xml is `enter code here`


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget3x3all"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/backgroundImage2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/widget31"
 android:layout_width="100dip"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_height="100dip"
 android:layout_gravity="right"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:previewImage="@drawable/emptyboy"
 android:scaleType="fitEnd"
 android:textColor="#ffffff" >

 </ImageView>
 <ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/widget32"
 android:layout_width="100dip"
 android:layout_height="100dip"
 android:layout_gravity="right"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:src="@drawable/middleheart1"
 android:scaleType="fitEnd"
 android:textColor="#ffffff"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/widget33"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

 </ImageView>


 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/widget33"
 android:layout_width="100dip"
 android:layout_height="100dip"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:previewImage="@drawable/emptyboy"
 android:scaleType="fitEnd"
 android:textColor="#ffffff" >

 </ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `widgetView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageid, bitmap);`

Where `bitmap` is `getImageBitmap()` (don't forget to check it for `null`):

```
public Bitmap getImageBitmap() {
    Uri uri =  getImageUri();
    Bitmap image = null;
    if (App.widgetImageCache.containsKey(uri)) {
        image = App.widgetImageCache.get(uri);
    }
    if (image == null && uri != null) {
        try {
            image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
            App.widgetImageCache.put(uri, image);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e);
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

Where `App.widgetImageCache` is `WeakHashMap`:

```
public static WeakHashMap<Uri, Bitmap> widgetImageCache = new WeakHashMap<>();
```